# Selected Image not displaying from YPImagePicker

Tags: swift, uiimage

So I am having an issue with displaying the selectedImage from the `YPImagePicker`, I normally do not like using third party resources but the image picker is exactly what I was looking for. Anyways the selected image is not displaying in the next view controller. I feel like my code is correct but obviously I guess not. No errors as well.

*** **Edited code below to the working code thanks to the mate below.**

```swift
// First VC to open imagePicker
  @IBAction func cameraButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        let picker = YPImagePicker()
        picker.didFinishPicking { [unowned picker] items, cancelled in

            if let photo = items.singlePhoto {
                let shareVC =    self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:   "SharePhotoController") as! SharePhotoViewController
                shareVC.selectedImage = photo.modifiedImage ?? photo.image
               picker.pushViewController(shareVC, animated: true)


            }
        present(picker, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

// Code for second VC that should display the selected image

```
 @IBOutlet weak var finalPhoto: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var addCaptionTextField: UITextField!

    var selectedImage: UIImage?


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

   self.finalPhoto.image = selectedImage
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6Ll0.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assign the photo to a vc that you don't present ( which is `sharePostVC` )

```
picker.dismiss(animated: true) {
   if let photo = items.singlePhoto {  
     let shareVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SharePhotoController") as! SharePhotoViewController
      shareVC.selectedImage = photo.modifiedImage ?? photo.image
      self.picker.pushViewController(shareV, animated: true) 
   }
}
```

To avoid crashes also remove `didSet` part and assign the image to the imageview inside `viewDidLoad` of `SharePhotoViewController`

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me so quick. When I call picker.dismiss(animated: true) { ... it closes the picker after I select the image and does not push me to the next VC..

Comment: Do you embed the current vc inside a naivation if so use `self.navigationController?` or present see edit

Comment: So with the YPImagePicker, I cannot use self.navigationController because I wont have access to their back button to take me back to the picker if needed. They recommend using picker.pushViewController.. I edited my answer above with the code you included. The picker now takes me to the final ViewController as before, however the image is still not being displayed.  Using picker.dismiss still closes out the picker and takes me back to the home page. I even tried removing the if canceled {... and still the same thing. Do you see anything wrong with what I edited?

Comment: Did you removed `didSet` and assigned the image inside `viewDidLoad` ????

Comment: Sorry no I did not. I do not know the best way to do that. Would it be  ```swift var selectedImage: UIImage?``` and in swift ```swift viewDidLoad...  selectedImage = finalPhoto?.image```  ???

Comment: It worked!! thanks so much! I've been stuck on this for 3 days. I accepted your answer. Thanks again!